# Proving a function of set is bijective.

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

I want to show that $\mathcal P(A\cup B)$ equipotent $\mathcal P(A)\times \mathcal P(B)$, with $A,B\neq\emptyset$ and $A\cap B=\emptyset$. So I have to find a bijective function from any side I want to any side I want.

What I thought of is:

$$f:\mathcal P(A)\times \mathcal P(B)\to \mathcal P(A\cup B), f(S,T)=S\cup T.$$

Or there is another problem:

$A,B$ are equipotent, does it imply that $\mathcal P(A), \mathcal P(B)$ are equipotent?

and here also I was thinking of these functions:

$f:A\to\ B$, bijective.

And $g:\mathcal P(A)\to\mathcal P(B), g(S)=\{f(a) | f(a) \in S, S\subseteq \mathcal P(B)\}$.

And I think that these functions are bijective but how do I prove it, because these functions does not take elements as inputs, but sets. Are there some ways to prove this? What do I think about?

Comment: Sets can be elements (and all elements are sets in a way).

Answer (score 1):

Your ideas are correct. Let us consider the first function $f$. If $f(S_1,T_1)=f(S_2,T_2)$, then $S_1\cup T_1=S_2\cup T_2$. But$$S_1\cup T_1=S_2\cup T_2\implies(S_1\cup T_1)\cap A=(S_2\cup T_2)\cap A\iff S_1=S_2$$and, by the same argument, $T_1=T_2$. Therefore, $f$ is injective.

And if $X\in\mathcal{P}(A\cup B)$, $X=f(X\cap A,X\cap B)$. Therefore, $f$ is surjective.

Can you do the rest now?

Comment: Wait, why $f(S_1, T_1) = f(S_2,T_2) \implies S_1\cup T_1 = S_2\cup T_1$? shouldn't it be $T_2$? Also what is your intuition behind writing these?

Comment: Typo! I've edited my answer.

Comment: And the line after that?  can you explain it a bit more?

Comment: I had the same typo there. Is it clear now?

Comment: Not really, Why $(S_1\cup T_1)\cap A \Leftrightarrow S_1=S_2$?

Comment: I did not write that. What I wrote was that $(S_1\cup T_1)\cap A=(S_2\cup T_2)\cap A\iff S_1=S_2$. That's so because $S_1\cup T_1)\cap A=S_1$ and $S_2\cup T_2)\cap A=S_2$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $g:\wp(A\cup B)$ be prescribed by:$$U\mapsto\langle A\cap U,B\cap U\rangle$$Now it is enough to prove that $g\circ f$ and $f\circ g$ are identities on $\wp(A)\times\wp(B)$ and $\wp(A\cup B)$ respectively, because a function is bijective if and only if it has an inverse.

For this observe that: $$\left\langle S,T\right\rangle \stackrel{f}{\mapsto}S\cup T\stackrel{g}{\mapsto}\left\langle (S\cup T)\cap S,(S\cup T)\cap T\right\rangle=\left\langle S,T\right\rangle $$
and: $$U\stackrel{g}{\mapsto}\left\langle A\cap U,B\cap U\right\rangle \stackrel{f}{\mapsto}(A\cap U)\cup(B\cap U)=U$$